# How to check if a number is within given range?

Tags: iphone

I have an age 24, and I want to return `TRUE` if 24 is within the range of 20 to 38, else `FALSE`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: But your profile says you’re 23 years old.

Comment: I am asking an example, now saying my age :-P

Comment: It was fun, not a question, I am teaching a student that how can he ask a question to stackoverflow and take help, so I put this simple and meaningful question :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return (age >= 20 && age <= 38);
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Very basic question. You know about if/else?

```
if (age >= 20 && age <= 38) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Or

```
return (age >= 20 && age <= 38) ? true : false;
```

Or

```
return (age >= 20 && age <= 38);
```

Comment: Oh thanks, of course this is wrong! Shouldn't post on stackoverflow right after standing up... fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (age > 19 && age < 39) { return true; } else { return false; }
```